# Only one client can be connected to my OpenVPN server on my LAN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I set up OpenVPN on my Raspberry Pi the other day. It was rough at the beginning, with me being absolutely clueless, but I managed.

I created client `.ovpn` files for my iPhone, iPad, and MacBook. For some reason, only one device can be connected to the VPN at a time, on my local network. For instance, if my iPhone is connected, my Mac and iPad cannot connect, but if my Mac is connected, my iPhone and iPad can't connect. However, I tried connecting on a different network, and all three of my devices connected with no problem.

I followed the [ReadWrite](http://readwrite.com/2014/04/10/raspberry-pi-vpn-tutorial-server-secure-web-browsing/) tutorial as well as the [BBC](http://.com/news/technology-33548728) tutorial.

Just incase, my `server.conf` file looks like this:

```
local 192.168.1.238 # SWAP THIS NUMBER WITH YOUR RASPBERRY PI IP ADDRESS
dev tun
proto tcp
port 443
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/RaspiVPN.crt # SWAP XX WITH YOUR SERVER NAME
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/RaspiVPN.key # SWAP XX WITH YOUR SERVER NAME
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh1024.pem # IF YOU CHANGED YOUR ENCRYPTION TO 2048, CHANGE THAT HERE
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
# server and remote endpoints
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
# Add route to Client routing table for the OpenVPN Server
push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255"
# Add route to Client routing table for the OpenVPN Subnet
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
# your local subnet
push "route 192.168.1.238 255.255.255.0" # SWAP THE IP NUMBER WITH YOUR RASPBERRY PI IP ADDRESS
# Set primary domain name server address to the SOHO Router
# If your router does not do DNS, you can use Google DNS 8.8.8.8
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8" # THIS SHOULD ALREADY MATCH YOUR OWN ROUTER ADDRESS AND SHOULD NOT NEED TO BE CHANGED
# Override the Client default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and
# 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of
# overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ta.key 0
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
duplicate-cn
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 1
```

An my `client.ovpn`: (Obviously they are different for each device but this is the "base.")

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote REMOVED 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
ns-cert-type server
key-direction 1
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 1
mute 20
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
REMOVED
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
REMOVED
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
REMOVED
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
REMOVED
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

Comment: Saucy question: Does an OpenVPN server allow more than one connection in the first place?  See here: https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn/issues/180#issuecomment-327683431

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be in the following lines:

```
# server and remote endpoints
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
# Add route to Client routing table for the OpenVPN Server
push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255"
# Add route to Client routing table for the OpenVPN Subnet
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
```

Basically you configure 10.8.0.1 correctly and .2 incorrectly, so as far as I can see, only 10.8.0.1 is used correctly, and then all slots are full. Altering this should fix your issue.

Comment: I think I user stand. Would I add "push "route 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.255"" under "push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255""?

Comment: Yeah, I think adding that will fix it.

Comment: It seems to have had no effect

Comment: Did you restart the OpenVPN services after configuring them?

Comment: Yes of course. I was still able to connect one, just not two at a time.

Comment: Hmm... I'm sorry but I have too little experience with OpenVPN to know where this is going wrong then.

Comment: I'll leave the answer here for others to take a reference at, so they might spot the problem earlier, and remove it when a new answer is posted.